# CV = driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[5]/button')) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm making a youtube tool but when I run the code, it gives me this error.

`CV = driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[5]/button')) TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`

Here is the code.

```
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.set_window_size(700,800)
        U = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        U = str(U)
        text = "L "
        text = str(text)
        C = 0
        V = self.spinBox_2.text()
        V = int(V)
        while (C < V):
            driver.get(U)
            time.sleep(5)
            CV = driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[5]/button'))
            CV.click()
            C = C + 1
```

Comment: Don't overuse tags: PyQt is irrelevant for the issue. Besides, you should *not* use blocking functions (such as `time.sleep()`) if you're executing the above in the main thread. And if you're using threads instead, you should not access UI elements, since widgets are not thread-safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
CV = driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[5]/button'))
```

This line causes the problem. The function `WebDriver.find_element` has the following definition:

```py
def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None) -> WebElement:
```

And the definition of `By`:

```py
class By(object):
    """
    Set of supported locator strategies.
    """

    ID = "id"
    XPATH = "xpath"
    LINK_TEXT = "link text"
    PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT = "partial link text"
    NAME = "name"
    TAG_NAME = "tag name"
    CLASS_NAME = "class name"
    CSS_SELECTOR = "css selector"
```

So you should call

```py
CV = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="movie_player"]/div[5]/button')
```

By.* is of type `str` and thus is not callable.

When using `WebDriver.find_element`, you need to supply the content as a second argument.